# Error: Could not find or load main class Java, because class file anme and class name are different?

Tags: java, eclipse

I can not get some simple Java code to run in Eclipse. My code is as follows:

```
 class DrinkAgeTest{
    static int age =14;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        if (age >=21){
            System.out.println("you may drink");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("you may not drink,come back in " + (21-age));
        }
    }
 }
```

My class created in the source folder is named `MathLearning`. When I try to run my code I get the following error message:

> Error: Could not find or load main class MathLearning

Is it because my class `DrinkAgetest` is different from the class file name, which is named `MathLearning`?If so how do I fix it. I couldn't find a rename button on the src right click menu.

Answer (score 1):

which class have main that is must be public..

```
public class DrinkAgeTest{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

How many source files do you have?
What is in them?

If it's just one - say "A.java" make sure it defines "public class A" in itself.
As said by others already, the class name must match the file name. Then go to 
a command prompt and do "javac A.java". This will produce file A.class. 
Then again from a command prompt do "java A". This will run your A.class file.

"javac" is the Java compiler
"java" is the JVM

Renaming the class file is not the way to do.

Answer (score 0):

The class name and the name of the file containing the class have to be the same.

If you are using eclipse, it should fix it for you automatically.

Comment: Is there anyway to rename the class file?

Comment: well it doesen't ,thats why I asked.

Comment: Just delete the .class file. Rename your .java file from MathLearning.java to DrinkAgeTest.java. Compile and run. Are you using an IDE for your development?

Answer (score 0):

To rename your class:

Right click on the class DrinkAgetest in your src folder, and click **Refactor**. Then click **Rename...**

If renaming the class doesn't fix the problem (it shouldn't fix it), then try what subash said:

change `class DrinkAgeTest` to `public class DrinkAgeTest`.

There could be other problems, possibly your compiler is looking for the wrong class altogether because you deleted it or something.